# ¿Porque nodejs se traga mi memoria ram con este codigo?

Tags: javascript, next.js

amigos, se me esta presentando un problema en la cual necesito su ayuda.

Estoy haciendo una pagina web en nextjs. Lo raro es, que al usar dos veces un mismo componente nodejs se vuelve loco y llega a consumir hasta 1.5gb( probado en mxlinux y windows 8.1).

https://ibb.co/PtvQTSJ --> pantallazo

si solo uso una vez renderizo el componente el consumo de nodejs maximo es 300mb

```
<div className={styleProduct.pitems}>
        <h1 className={styleProduct.titleproject}> Ultimas noticias </h1>
        <div className={styleProduct.items}>
          {items &&
            items.map((item) => (
              <Product key={item.id} item={item} showAs="item" /> // --> componente con bug
            ))}
        </div>
      </div>
```

Si hago esto -renderizar el componente dos veces -nodejs se consume hasta 1.5gb en memoria ram. Aunque a veces con solo una vez tambien sucedia el alto consumo

```
<div className={styleProduct.pitems}>
        <h1 className={styleProduct.titleproject}> Nuestros proyectos </h1>
        <p className={`${styleProduct.text_section_top} ${`text-center`}`}>
          Con su valioso apoyo muchas personas se benefician.
          <br />
          Conoce mejor
          <strong> nuestros Proyectos </strong>
        </p>
        <div className={styleProduct.items}>
        {items &&
            items.map((item) => (
              <Product key={item.id} item={item} showAs="item" /> // --> componente con bug
            ))}
        </div>
      </div>

<div className={styleProduct.pitems} id="noticias">
        <h1 className={styleProduct.titleproject}> Ultimas noticias </h1>
        <div className={styleProduct.items}>
          {items &&
            items.map((item) => (
              <Product key={item.id} item={item} showAs="item" /> // --> componente con bug
            ))}
        </div>
      </div>
```

el componente Product

```
return (
    <div className={style.item}>
      <div className={style.itemimg}>
        <Link legacyBehavior href={`/blog/${convertToPath(item.title)}`}>
          <a>
            <Image
              src={item.image}
              alt={item.description}
              width={500}
              height={500}
              style={{
                width: "100%",
                height: "100%",
                display: "block",
                objectFit: "cover",
              }}
            />
          </a>
        </Link>
      </div>

      <div>
        <h3>
          <Link legacyBehavior href={`/blog/${convertToPath(item.title)}`}>
            <a className={style.titleview}>{item.title}</a>
          </Link>
        </h3>
      </div>

      <div>{`$${item.price}`}</div>
      <div><CartButton item={item} /></div>
    </div>
  );
```

Ahora la pregunta es ¿porque sucede esto?

¿alguien me puede explicar porque este bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solucion que encontre fue cambiar el componente Image de nextjs por la etiqueta html img de esta forma.

```
<div className={style.itemimg}>
        <Link legacyBehavior href={`/blog/${convertToPath(item.title)}`}>
          <a>
            <img
              src={item.image}
              alt={item.description}
              width={500}
              height={500}
              style={{
                width: "100%",
                height: "100%",
                display: "block",
                objectFit: "cover",
              }}
            />
          </a>
        </Link>
      </div>
```

Y listo nodejs dejo de comerse toda mi ram.